# Ignore case sensitive in Python

Tags: python

I want to check if a variable's value is one of 'Val' or 'val'.
I can't use `var.lower()` because the variable can be None.
I know I can use `var in ['Val','val']` or `str(var).lower()` but I look for a nicer way...

Comment: how this values  `vaL`, `value`, `" VaL "`(with trailing spaces) should be treated?

Comment: In this case I can assume that the other letters are low anyway. I have problem only with the first.

Comment: what about my last item `" VaL "` (with trailing spaces) ?

Answer (score 2):

you can just combine those tests:

```
if var and var.lower() == 'val':
```

[`and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and) short-circuits: if `var` is `None`, `var.lower()` is not executed.

or if `var` can also have other types and you want to be a bit more explicit:

```
if var is not None and var.lower() == 'val':
```